# How to display panel on click event of menu?

Tags: extjs4, panel

I would like to know how to display certain panel on click event of menu? I have added menu items in viewport and listening for 'click' event of menu items in controller. Upto this point its working fine but when I use Ext.widget() method to get panel and call show() method of that panel, nothing is happening.

My code to handle menu item click event is as follows :

```
viewPortMenu_ClickHandler : function(menu, item, event, options) {
        var panelToShow = null;
        if (item.text == '4D view') {
                panelToShow = Ext.widget('employeeDistribution');
        }
        if (panelToShow != null) {
                panelToShow.show();
        }
}
```

Please let me know why this is not working / what is the preferred way to display panels at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I just had to add the newly created panel inside viewport using add() method of viewport.